# How combine two query in mysql which have all different column name

Tags: php, sql

this is the query for search product. The data have product listing from the different two table.

```
$where = " Jewellery_Title like '%$id%' or Jewellery_SKU like '%$id%' and Jewellery_Status='Active'";
// $where_s = implode(' and ', $where);
$sql = "select * from jewellery where (".$where."".$jewellery_name." ) $metal_where  order by rank asc";
$res1 = query($con,$sql);
$total1 = row($res1);

$where = " Ring_Title like '%$id%' or Ring_SKU like '%$id%' $ring_name
and Ring_Status='Active'";
$sql = "select * from rings where (".$where.")  $metal_where order by rank asc";
$res2 = query($con,$sql);
$total2 = row($res2);
```

Comment: Are you looking for MySql joins?? [Refer this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) and show your table schema here and explain which type of output you want.

Comment: What might be more helpful, for me at least, is the table syntax + some dummy data. You can use [SqlFiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to easily copy/paste people workable data.

Comment: Use `UNION` and rename the columns to the same thing using `AS`.

Comment: Hello i want pagination in php so i want combine the query.

Answer (score 2):

Use alias in mysql query as i mention above and run the array merge .

```
$sql=select jewelleryname as name from jewellery
$sql1=select ringname as name from rings 
// more code
 $total = row($res1);
 $total1 = row($res2);
$C = array_merge($total , $total1);
```

if you want join query use this

```
select jewelleryname as name from jewellery
UNION ALL
select ringname as name from rings
```

Comment: I want merge query not result array because i need the pagination in php.

Comment: select Jewellery_Id as Jewellery_id from jewellery UNION ALL select Ring_Id as ring_id from rings.
i have used this query but i have get result from only jewellery table bu i have not get data from rings table.

Comment: use common alias for id and name . select Jewellery_Id as id from jewellery UNION ALL select Ring_Id as id from rings

Comment: sorry friend i have still getting result of only jewellery table.

Comment: refer all column should be similar to each other query  - https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/union_all.php